Databricks: Asynchronous Calls to Functions when using ThreadPoolExecutor and Concurrent Calls using executor
We have a Databricks function
import requests as req

def my_rest_api_call(my_list)

which internally calls a Service URL using
resp = req.post(url = serviceUrl, data = webParams)

This returns back responseData in the form of JSON
We call this my_rest_api_call almost 50K times using:
with ThreadPoolExecutor(concurrency) as executor: 

      results = executor.map(my_rest_api_call, listChunks) 

Here concurrency we are putting around 10
Sometimes these APIs take too long, so we need to stop them if it takes more time.
The code that actually does the API call we would like to surround with this async wrapper to gracefully stop and bubble up an error if the call to my_rest_api_call takes more than X time (let's say 3 min)

You ca try this code in your scenarios.
import asyncio
import requests as req
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

async def my_rest_api_call_timeout(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.run_in_executor(None, req.get, url)
    try:
        response = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=0.01) #give timeout 280 in your case
        print(response.json() )
        return response.json()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        raise TimeoutError("API call timed out")

async def call_api_with_timeout(url):
    try:
        return await my_rest_api_call_timeout(url)
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print("API call timed out:", e)

async def main():
    concurrency = 10
    listChunks = ["https://postman-echo.com/get?test=123","https://postman-echo.com/get?test=123","https://postman-echo.com/get?test=123"]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(concurrency) as executor:
        await asyncio.gather(*[call_api_with_timeout(url) for url in listChunks])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    await main()


Here i made get request, you change it to post and pass parameters option to you function like below.
loop.run_in_executor(None, req.get, url, params,body)
Output:

For given timeout 0.01 i am getting time out exception.
